# Mail.app: How to use multiple From: addresses for the same Gmail account?

Tags: email, gmail

[This guide](http://email.about.com/od/macosxmailtips/qt/Use_Multiple_From_Addresses_with_a_Mac_OS_X_Mail_Account.htm) explains how to add `From` addresses to Mail.app:

**Use Multiple From: Addresses with an OS X Mail Account**

To set up multiple addresses for one account in Mac OS X Mail:

1. Select Mail | Preferences... from the menu in Mac OS X Mail.
2. Go to the Accounts category.
3. Highlight the desired account.
4. Enter all email addresses you want to use with this account in the Email Address: field.
5. Separate the addresses by commas (like "me@example.com,­me_the_pro@example.com").
   After you have closed the configuration dialog and saved the new settings you can send mail from all these email addresses.

I’ve done this for my Gmail account, and indeed, when composing a new message in Mail.app, I can select which `From` address to use for this mail. **However, no matter which one I select, the `From:` header is still set to my main Gmail address — so the email recipient still sees my main address.**

Is there a way to make this work as expected, without adding the secondary email address as a separate account?

**Note:** I’ve added the secondary email address via the Gmail web interface → Settings → Accounts → Send mail as.

Comment: Can you get away with setting the Reply-To header This is the one the user should see

Answer (score 7):

In Mail 9 (el capitan) this is done by adding the new address as an "Alias" in the Preferences.

Mail > Preference > Accounts tab > Account information tab. Above the "Email address" Field you will see "Alias". Click, and click "edit Alias". Click the plus (+) icon on the bottom left, and add the email address and name.

Of course the address must be properly set up and authorised as an extra account in the Gmail interface itself first.

Gmail > Settings > Accounts and Import > Send mail as. Treat as alias must be on (checked).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this did the trick:

Go to *Gmail* → *Settings* → *Send mail as…* → select the secondary address → *edit info* → check *“treat as an alias”*.

Comment: You mean /uncheck/ "treat as an alias", right?